# Using arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, metadata, error-000816

I don't know if it is a bug or my lack of python skills, but I keep getting 'ERROR 000816 The tool is not valid' in my python script when I call [ExportMetadata_conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Export_Metadata/00120000000t000000/)

Initially, I was attempting this on an sde database, but then I tried to take a step back just match the example in the documentation and use a file geodb:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/data"
#set local variables
dir = arcpy.GetInstallInfo("desktop")["InstallDir"]
translator = dir + "Metadata/Translator/ESRI_ISO2ISO19139.xml"
arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion ("data.gdb/roads", translator, 
    "roads_19139.xml")
```

But I received the same error.

If anyone is successfully calling this method, does your code match the documentation?

Comment: I used the code sample you posted above and just substituted my data.  It ran fine and generated the output xml file.  I'm running ArcInfo 10 on XP.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the above issue with ESRI? I'm getting the same error! Thanks,
Frank

Comment: I ended up using @Kenton Williams answer.  No resolution with Esri apart from a bug ID, which I don't have (this was logged at my previous employer and I didn't keep the ID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had better success using the XSLTransform_conversion operation in my Python geoprocessing scripts.  There are a few ESRI-supplied XSL files in the C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcToolBox\Stylesheets directory (on a 32-bit machine).  Here's an example of the line using the XSL transform I used in a python script I published to ArcGIS Server:

results = gp.XSLTransform_conversion(inputFC, xslFile, outputFileName)

This returns a formatted file.  I chose to have HTML as an output, but it will output XML if you want.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the 32-bit version of python. I know this is an old post but someone might stumble on it looking for an answer. See https://geonet.esri.com/thread/94637.

Comment: this is the right answer (sad as it is)

Answer (score 1):

[Python Errors in IDLE, but Works in ArcCatalog???](https://geonet.esri.com/message/16094#16094)

You need to use GacUtil to register the DLL's properly for Metadata so that ArcPy can use them.  All instructions are in the ArcGIS forum post link above.